# How to select a dynamic number link using WebDriver for Java

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

I'm trying to select a dynamic number link in *Webdriver*. The problem is this: 
The *xpath* and `href` are both dependent on the order ID which changes per order. In this particular case:

```
XPath = "//*[@id='transSummaryRow_1195908']/td[1]/a"
href ="ftransDetails.aspx?FTID=1195908&OID=904096">1195908"
```

Here's what I tried, but it's not working.

```
public static WebElement lnk_TransHistPayId(WebDriver driver){
    element = driver.findElement(By.linkText("ftransDetails.aspx?FTID="+"\\d+"+"&OID"+"="+"\\d+"));
    return element;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
//or this can be done also: By css = By.cssSelector("[id^='transSummaryRow_']/td[1]/a");
By css = By.cssSelector("[href^='ftransDetails.aspx?FTID=']");

public static WebElement lnk_TransHistPayId(WebDriver driver){
    element = driver.findElement(css);
    return element;
}
```